# Reset DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am importing a textfile into a DGV, the textfile contains a list of unordered values. I also have a textbox that i enter a value into and it displays the number of values i specified into the DGV. I also have a button that sorts the values in the DGV, which all works great. My question is how do i reset the DGV back to where they are unordered? this is the approach i attempted:

```
private void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  mergeSortButton.Enabled = true;
  quickSortButton.Enabled = true;
  selectionSortButton.Enabled = true;
  displayDGV.Rows.Clear();
  displayDGV.Refresh();

  if (File.Exists(DATA_FILE_NAME))
    fileIn = File.OpenText(DATA_FILE_NAME);
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show(DATA_FILE_NAME + " does not exist", "Abort Execution",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return;
  }
  if (listCountTextBox.ReadInt(out index))
    for (int i = 1; i <= index; i++)
      idList.Add(Int32.Parse(fileIn.ReadLine().Replace("-", "")));
  fileIn.Close();
  DisplayIDList(displayDGV);

}
```

I figured I could just clear the DGV and import the values back into the DGV. Probably not the best approach, but it's not even working for me. I am still in the process of learning c#. Any insight would be awesome!

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to load the txt file to the datagrid you may load it at first to a listbox e.g. listBox1, and then to a DataTable. The datagrid can use the DataTable as its DataSource. You may then specify how many numbers your grid will display. For the above,  you may use as an example the followning code,

```
private void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //........
        StreamReader fileIn;
        displayDGV.DataSource = null;
        displayDGV.Rows.Clear();
        displayDGV.Refresh();
        displayDGV.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
        string DATA_FILE_NAME = "C:\\Dgvnums.txt";//e.g. a sample name 
        if (File.Exists(DATA_FILE_NAME))
            fileIn = File.OpenText(DATA_FILE_NAME);
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(DATA_FILE_NAME + " does not exist", "Abort Execution",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        int lincnt = 0;
        string teststr = "";//the following counts the Lines included in the txt file
        while (!fileIn.EndOfStream)
        {
            teststr = fileIn.ReadLine();
            if (teststr != "")
            {
                lincnt++;
            }
        }
        fileIn.Close();
        int index = int.Parse(textBox1.Text.ToString());
        if (index > lincnt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("THE FILE CONTAINS LESS NUMBERS THAN YOU HAVE SPECIFIED");
            return;
        }
        fileIn = File.OpenText(DATA_FILE_NAME);
        listBox1.Items.Clear();//the folloing loads the numbers in the listBox1
        for (int i = 1; i <= index; i++)
        {
            string toreadstr = fileIn.ReadLine();
            if (toreadstr.Contains("-"))
            {
                toreadstr = toreadstr.Replace("-", "");
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add(Int32.Parse(toreadstr));
        }
        fileIn.Close();
        DataTable mytab = new DataTable();
        mytab.Columns.Add();
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            object[] numbr = new object[1];
            numbr[0] = new object();
            numbr[0] = (object)listBox1.Items[i];
            mytab.LoadDataRow(numbr, true);
        }
        displayDGV.DataSource = mytab;
        displayDGV.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Mynumbers";
        displayDGV.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        displayDGV.Refresh();
    }
```

Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

do not filter your original model. instead make a second one and filter that. pseudo code if you will...

```
if (No Filter applied) 
{
    ApplyToDG(originalModel) 
} 
else  
{ 
    newModel = originalModel; 
    ApplyFilterTo(newModel); 
    ApplyToDG(newModel); 
}
```